# ASP.NET mvc4 - form elements inside ICollection loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to make an editing function where you can add metafields (= specific fields for a category) to a category.

What I want to do in the view is

```
foreach (App.Models.Metafield field in Model.Category.Metafields)
{
   <div class="field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => field.Name, new { @class = "form-control title" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => field.Type, Model.MetaTypes, new { @class = "form-control type" })
   </div>
}
```

The problem is that the Metafields are not added to the viewModel when I hit the save button. So I guess the `field.Name` and `field.Type` should be replaced by something else..

Comment: did you add include statement in the linq query? in order to tell the entity framework to load Category and to load Metafields

Answer (score 0):

This can't work this way because the sent form can't contain these dynamically generated fields with the same name.

However, you can collect the data from these dynamic fields using js and serialize it into a hidden field just before submitting the form, then you can parse it in your server side.
Here is an example with jquery:

```
$('#save-btn').click(function(e) {
    $hidden = $("#hidden");
    $hidden.val(getDynamicData());
});

function getDyanmicData() {
    var data;
    $fields = $(".field");
    // get children and calculate data

    return data;
}
```

This may be a bit too 'manual work', but I find it useful to know what's happening. For other solutions you can search form dynamic forms in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
@for(int i=0;i<=Model.Category.Metafields.count();i++)
{
   <div class="field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m[i].Name, new { @class = "form-control title" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m[i].Type, Model.MetaTypes, new { @class = "form-control type" })
   </div>
}
```